# Conda install taking too long

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I had Anaconda and conda installed on my machine before, but deleted the `.bash_profile` conda script in my `~/.bash_profile`. Then, I deleted the anaconda navigator, and the entire anaconda3 directory from `/opt/anaconda3`.

Then installed the anaconda navigator and conda again, but they came with python 3.8 installed. I wanted to downgrade Python to `3.7.4`, so I run the following command: (in the base env) `conda install python=3.7.4`.

It has been stuck in `Solving Environment` for about 10 minutes or so, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: This is not unexpected, conda has to solve hundreds of dependencies to make that big of a change work out. I would suggest that you instead install the previous version of the `anaconda` package, which should go much faster because all the package dependency versions are specified. `conda install anaconda=2020.07 python=3.7` should go much faster (I hope!).

Comment: _I want to downgrade Python to 3.7.4, so I run the following command: (in the base env)_ Don't do that! Making many changes to the base environment is a recipe for disaster, it's best to only touch it when you need to update conda. Create a separate environment for each project/application.

Comment: *strongly* agree with @AMC. create a new environment.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem in Anaconda 4.10.3 and was fixed by creating a new environment, as suggested by @Paul H. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30032772)